# Python Pandas to_datetime removes underscore

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, formatting, underscore.js

In my application time is stored in this manner:

> 05-04-2017_12:28:26.758369

So I wrote:

```
df[timestamp_lbl] = pd.to_datetime(df[timestamp_lbl],
                                   format="%d-%m-%Y_%H:%M:%S.%f")
```

When I print df[timestamp_lbl], I get:

> 05-04-2017 12:28:26.758369

The underscore is now missing. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Note: I need the column to have a datetime64 and not a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `format` argument only tells `to_datetime` what kind of syntax to expect when it's parsing a date string.  But once it's converted to a Pandas Datetime object, its printed representation is always the same.  If you need to print out its value at some point, you can use the `.strftime()` method without changing its `dtype`:

```
ts = "05-04-2017_12:28:26.758369"
tsobj = pd.to_datetime(ts,format="%d-%m-%Y_%H:%M:%S.%f")

print(tsobj.strftime("%d-%m-%Y_%H:%M:%S.%f"))
'05-04-2017_12:28:26.758369'
```